# RedisSearch get max date in JSON

Tags: sql, sql-server, redis, node-redis, redisjson

I use RedisSearch to query my products

I want to get last 10 products changed

In SQL I can do that with:

```
Select top 10 * from products order by max(changedate) desc
```

How can I get the same result using RedisSearch?

Comment: *"In SQL I can do that with:"* In SQL [Server] That statement would error... (Unless the table only has the column `changedate`, which I doubt.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a range query with sortby.

```
FT.SEARCH products "@changedate:[somedate inf]" SORTBY changedate DESC
```

Please note that the smaller the date range you give, the faster the query will execute. You can fo `[-inf inf]` but that will not be efficiant.